# How can I ensure that auth.dll can be loaded?

Tags: c#, c++, clr, crypto++

I'm trying to use crypto++ in **c++ clr class library**.

The problem is that I get an error as I run the app, but it builds successfully.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'auth.dll' or one of its dependencies. A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045A)
   at ConsoleApp52.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

This error only occurs when I include anything from crypto++

```cpp
#include "dll.h"
#include "sha.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "hex.h"
```

If I remove the following lines, it works.

I've tried copying the cryptopp.dll to the bin/x64/Debug and bin/Debug, but it did not resolve the issue.
What else do I need to include? Am I Missing something?

Dependecies:
[image: dependencies]

[image: libs]

[image: build]

[image: solution]

Comment: I was very cautios to copy the x64 libs, but I might have accidentally copied the x32 .libs to the dependencies, I've copied it to the dependecies again and now I get another error:

`System.IO.FileLoadException: A procedure imported by 'auth.dll' could not be loaded.
   at ConsoleApp52.Program.Main(String[] args)`

Comment: @porsekin So.. Is the `auth.dll` in the same directory as the application you are running (or in the directory present in the PATH environment variable)? See: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order).

Comment: @rustyx,AlgirdasPreidžius
Thank you guys. Now it works! I had to copy and include the x64 version to the build folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error code `0x8007045A` most often means 32/64 bit DLL incompatibility.

If you're using native DLLs with managed code, make sure to use 64-bit versions on a 64-bit OS.